# How to detect model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have rails app with **devise** gem.
How to detect in rails app the model name for devise?

I want to make a gem, and I need to know the model, which uses devise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Devise.default_scope # => :user
```

Works for me in rails console with devise 1.5.3. Devise also provides `default_scope=` method, but you should use it carefully

Answer (score 0):

You can define which model you want devise to be used for.  When you do:

```
rails generate devise MODEL
```

Change MODEL for whatever model you want devise to be applied to. For example, you could do:

```
rails generate devise User
```

And that will create the necessary attributes in the **User** model, and if the User model doesn't exist, it will be created.

Notice that after this you will have to run `rake db:migrate` to apply the devise migrations to your existing database.

In other words, don't expect devise to define a model like "devise", but you have to define which model you want devise to be used for.

**EDIT**:

If you want to look for models that are already "using" Devise, you could look for this kind of declaration in the model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,...
```

Comment: This I understand. I want to make a gem, and I need to know the model, which uses devise.

Comment: So you want to look for existing models that are using Devise? I have edited my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: No I need to know the name of the class model. For example: User or Admin.